# What does base.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]") do inside ObservableCollection?

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I was looking around in `ObservableCollection<T>` using a decompiler and saw some curious `OnPropertyChanged` code that I'd never seen before.

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        ...
        base.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        base.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        ...
    }
}
```

What does the `OnPropertyChanged("Item[]")` call do and how would that be helpful when writing my own code?

It must be doing something different than a standard `OnPropertyChanged` call since 'Item' is not a property on the object and '`[]`' surely isn't part of 'any' property name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that notifies anything bound to the collection that item(s) have changed.

Comment: @mydogisbox If you are referring to detecting added/removed items, that is handled by INotifyCollectionChanged and its CollectionChanged event.  If you are referring to detecting a property change on an item within the collection, that is outside the scope of the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `OnPropertyChanged("Item[]")` is required to follow the spirit of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The data returned by the default indexer `Item` has changed.

In your specific example, the collection has been cleared, so if you are indexing into a specific item the collection, then you need to be notified that the object reference you are interested in may be different.

### Edit

After Kevin's comment about binding to an indexer, I wrote an app to test the binding.

I created an `ObservableCollection<int>` and populated like this:

```
this.Indexed.Add(1);
this.Indexed.Add(2);
this.Indexed.Add(3);
```

If you bind to something via the indexer like this, it will display `3`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Indexed[2]}" />
```

And then change the object at that index at runtime,

```
this.Indexed.Insert(2, 10);
```

The `TextBlock` will update and display the new value `10`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how binding with an indexer worked.  Are you saying that if you have `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyObservableCollection[2]}" />` the `Text` property has a live binding to the `ObservableCollection` and is not directly bound to the item itself? I never thought of it that way, but that seems to indicate that if I went into code and did a `ObservableCollection.Insert(2, newItem)`, then the UI would update and show the new item.  Makes perfect sense if thought through.

Comment: I'm not sure if that binding would update.  My main thought was that if it didn't raise the event for the Item property, then it wouldn't be accurately implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I just wrote a test application to see what would happen, and your binding suggestion works.  I'll edit the answer to include the important XAML.